# how to add an json array of object into array of objects?

Tags: javascript, json

For the json object :

```
 var str={  
  "roles":[
            {
                "roleId":"Abcd",
                "envRoleName": "0101",
                "roleName": "Admin",
                "envCode":"HosJ",
                "envName":"UoH"
            },
            {
                "roleId":"efgh",
                "envRoleName": "0102",
                "roldeName": "User",
                "envCode":"HosJ",
                "envName":"HosJ"
            }
        ]
       }
```

and I have an array  `const  available_roles: Role[] = []`

I am trying to insert each object from json array into the `Role[]` by

```
var json = JSON.parse(str); numParams = Object.keys(json.roles[0]).length;

for(j = 0 ; j < json.roles.length ; j++){
   if(j % numParams == 0){
      available_roles.push ( json.roles[j] );
   }
 }
```

The `available_roles` array is populated with 10 objects instead of just 2 objects. Can someone explain why this might be, please?

Comment: What you have is simply an object, not JSON. It's not something you can parse.

Comment: working fiddle?

Comment: yes here ...i have kept the only roles array ...my json consists of objects and array of objects ....

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just assign the object directly?

```
var json = JSON.parse(str);
for(j = 0 ; j < json.roles.length ; j++) {
  available_roles.push ( json.roles[j] );
}
```

Comment: if we push directly ...it pushes 10 objects into available roles based on the number of items in each object . since each object has 5 items ...vailable_roles: Array[10]
0
:
Object
envCode
:
"HosJ"
envName
:
"UoH"
envRoleName
:
"0101"
roleId
:
"Abcd"
roleName
:
"Admin"
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
Object
2
:
Object
3
:
Object
4
:
Object
5
:
Object
6
:
Object
7
:
undefined
8
:
undefined
9
:
undefined
length
:
10

Comment: Besides other answers already mentioned that the 'str' is object and not a string, you assign the role objects directly no need to deal with their individual members.

Answer (score 0):

No need of parse, Just do it directly becoz its already object.[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rjbqo0th/)

```
var str={  
  "roles":[
            {
                "roleId":"Abcd",
                "envRoleName": "0101",
                "roleName": "Admin",
                "envCode":"HosJ",
                "envName":"UoH"
            },
            {
                "roleId":"efgh",
                "envRoleName": "0102",
                "roldeName": "User",
                "envCode":"HosJ",
                "envName":"HosJ"
            }
        ]
       }


var availableuser = [];
for(j = 0 ; j < str.roles.length ; j++)
             {

                     console.log(str.roles[j])
                     availableuser.push(str.roles[j]);

             }

             console.log(availableuser);
```

Answer (score 0):

`str` is already a JSON object. 
You can use it directly without parsing:

```
var numParams = Object.keys(str.roles[0]).length;
for(j = 0 ; j < str.roles.length ; j++)
{
 if(j % numParams == 0){
     available_roles.push ( str.roles[j] );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Some observations :**

- As `str` is already a `JSON object` so no need to parse it again.
- You can push the `roles` into the `available_roles` array diectly. no need to do this type of condition `j % numParams == 0`.

**DEMO**

```js
var str = {
 "roles": [{
  "roleId": "Abcd",
  "envRoleName": "0101",
  "roleName": "Admin",
  "envCode": "HosJ",
  "envName": "UoH"
 }, {
  "roleId": "efgh",
  "envRoleName": "0102",
  "roldeName": "User",
  "envCode": "HosJ",
  "envName": "HosJ"
 }]
};

var json = str;
var available_roles = [];

for(j = 0 ; j < json.roles.length ; j++){
      available_roles.push(json.roles[j]);
 }
 
console.log(available_roles);
```